# How to slice interface in systemverilog (synthesizable)

Tags: arrays, interface, system-verilog, synthesis

I have the following synthesis issue:

```
// Variable instantiation
read_port_if #() mem_rp [N_INST*2] (); // Memory read port interface (each element in array is a single readport)

// module instantiation
memory #(
    .N_RPORT(N_INST*2)
  ) modMem (.*,
    .rPort(mem_rp)
  );

generate
  for (genvar iInst=0;iInst<N_INST;iInst++) begin
    accelerator #(
        .I_INST(iInst),
        .N_INST(N_INST)
      ) accelerator (.*,
        .mod_rp(mem_rp[(iInst*2)+:2]) // Expects an read port array of size 2
      );
  end
endgenerate
```

This code is fully functional however synthesis complains:
"The construct 'Interface Array Slice Indexing' is not supported".

How do I pass this subarray to the module without slicing the interface?
I would prefer not to rewrite my interface to allow for slicing as in [this blog post](https://bradpierce.wordpress.com/2014/07/06/how-to-slice-a-systemverilog-interface/) since this would take a lot of time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have created a work around for the problem but not a real answer to the problem.
Work around: pass the interface array to each accelerator block and select within the accelerator the correct interface.

Comment: However this work around gives my tons of analyse_elaborate warnings of the type: "xxxxx port 'xxxx' is not being used in accordance with its stated direction" since a lot of these ports are simply not driven/used in that block. This is not a problem except for bloating up the log files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create an intermediate signal and not slice in the port? Some verilog simulators have problem with this (VCS and Questa for exmaple).

```
// module instantiation
memory #(
    .N_RPORT(N_INST*2)
  ) modMem (.*,
    .rPort(mem_rp)
  );

generate
  for (genvar iInst=0;iInst<N_INST;iInst++) begin
    wire mem_rp_sliced = mem_rp[(iInst*2)+:2];
    accelerator #(
        .I_INST(iInst),
        .N_INST(N_INST)
      ) accelerator (.*,
        .mod_rp(mem_rp_sliced) // Expects an read port array of size 2
      );
  end
endgenerate
```